# How to fix print is not working in python with the random lib

Tags: python, random

I am creating a rock, paper, scissor game i just try the random lib but this what happens

```
C:\Users\Timothy\Desktop>python app1.py
2
Please choose 1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Siccors2
```

and this is the code that I create

```
import random
ai = (random.randint(1,3))
print(ai)
play = input("Please choose 1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Siccors")
if ai == play:
    print("Hello")
```

Comment: `play` is a string and won’t equal an int.

Comment: Ok Thanks if forgot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, the `input()` method returns a `string`. So, `play` will be a string `"1"` and `ai` will be an integer `1`. `"1" != 1`, hence your code will not execute the statements inside the `if` condition.

Chnage:

```
play = input("Please choose 1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Siccors")
```

To:

```
play = int(input("Please choose 1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Siccors"))
```